# Ifstream with string arrays and getline()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to add on to it to allow the user to store the array, just in case they have to do something or leave. I have tried to use `ifstream` to load a file with the array data from the previous execution. I have tried to use `getline()` to do so.

Here is what I have tried and I do not have enough arguments in the function call:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("C:\\users\\David\\Desktop\\dada\\array1.txt");
while(infile);
{
    for(int r = 0;r < 3000;r++)
    {
        cin.getline (names,r); //error here
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: here cin is the funtion you are trying, str is your string:  .    .    .     .
  getline (cin,str);

Comment: Besides fixing the `getline` call, you may also want to remove the semicolon after the `while` or you'll get an infinite loop that does nothing.

Comment: thanks for the tip w/ the semicolon, but i still get an error that says: No instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

Comment: Show the declaration of 'names'. It has to be a char* or a char array.

Comment: oh ok,but can i still have whole words not, "H","E","L","L","O"

Comment: What is the *exact* purpose of these loops? I don't think the code in this question can exactly do *anything* really useful; thus, I believe you have to be more specific on what is in the file and where you want to store it. More actual code (possibly one writing the file) would be useful.

Comment: no its okay i'll wait until i know a little more about c++ to do this